# gcc: "cannot find -lasound" when compiling on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, sdl, sdl-2, pkg-config

I am compiling a C++ program on Windows. The program uses the **SDL2** library. I run the following **pkg-config** command to obtain the correct flags to pass to the GCC compiler.

```
$ pkg-config sdl2 --cflags --libs
```

which gives output

```
-lpthread -lasound -IC:/sdl2/include/SDL2 -LC:/sdl2/lib -lSDL2
```

However when using these flags with GCC the program fails to compile, giving the error

> cannot find -lasound

Is this a library I need to obtain in order to use SDL2, or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Huh? It gives me `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows`, and no mention of `-lasound`. Where did you get SDL2? What are the contents of `sdl2.pc`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I got SDL2 via the Windows package manager, Scoop. The contents of `sdl2.pc` are
```
# sdl pkg-config source file

prefix=
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: sdl2
Description: Simple DirectMedia Layer is a cross-platform multimedia library designed to provide low level access to audio, keyboard, mouse, joystick, 3D hardware via OpenGL, and 2D video framebuffer.
Version: 2.0.10
Requires:
Conflicts:
Libs: -L${libdir}  -lSDL2
Libs.private: -lSDL2
Cflags: -I${includedir}/SDL2 -lpthread -lasound
```

Comment: I guess it must be an issue with the version of SDL2 being delivered by Scoop.

Comment: Yeah, either you modified this file accidentally, or Scoop ships broken files. I suggest downloading the official binaries for SDL2, or use MSYS2 packages.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

GCC not find this library. Find file libcomdlg32.a and find your -lasound file and copy -lasound file in folder, where's libcomdlg32.a file.